# Youtube iframe API events not triggering when player is added at later stage

Tags: javascript, youtube-iframe-api

I have an app where I inject a youtube iframe player (full iframe html snippet) at some point in time when a user requests a specific video. This could happen e.g. 30 seconds after loading the app or at any point in time, just not right after loading the app.

This seems to be a problem for the youtube API. In my code example below, you can see that the example isn't working because I'm adding the iframe player after a 1 second time. When you lower the timeout from 1000 to just 1ms, the code works fine.

Because of that test, I found out that the YT events aren't triggering because of my player being injected at a later point when the app has already been loaded for some time.

Is there a way to make the events trigger when the player isn't immediately added to the dom? Or can someone explain why the events only work when the player is added immediately to the page (even when the element itself is added after the script)

https://jsbin.com/vuhibelabi/1/edit?html,output

```
<div id="test" style="display:none;"></div>
    
    
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
      
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.id = 'iframe-demo';
      tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
    
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('existing-iframe-example', {
            events: {
              'onReady': onPlayerReady,
              'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
      }
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        document.getElementById('existing-iframe-example').style.borderColor = '#FF6D00';
      }
      function changeBorderColor(playerStatus) {
        var color;
        if (playerStatus == -1) {
          color = "#37474F"; // unstarted = gray
        } else if (playerStatus == 0) {
          color = "#FFFF00"; // ended = yellow
        } else if (playerStatus == 1) {
          color = "#33691E"; // playing = green
        } else if (playerStatus == 2) {
          color = "#DD2C00"; // paused = red
        } else if (playerStatus == 3) {
          color = "#AA00FF"; // buffering = purple
        } else if (playerStatus == 5) {
          color = "#FF6DOO"; // video cued = orange
        }
        if (color) {
          document.getElementById('existing-iframe-example').style.borderColor = color;
        }
      }
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        changeBorderColor(event.data);
      }
      
      function go(){
        var player = `<iframe id="existing-iframe-example"
            width="640" height="360"
            src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?enablejsapi=1"
            frameborder="0"
            style="border: solid 4px #37474F"
    ></iframe>`;
      document.querySelector("#test").innerHTML = player;
      document.querySelector("#test").style.display = "block";
      }
      
      setTimeout(function(){
        go();
      }, 1000)
      
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone in the same situation, I have switched to using the [JS-based solution](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Loading_a_Video_Player) instead of injecting a full iframe and that seems to work fine.